# How to parse the following long announcement?

Tags: grammar

The first 2 sentences are given as follows. I have no problem with these.

- お客様にお願いいたします。Thank  you to our customer.
- 鈴木伸ちゃんという３歳の男のお子さんが迷子になりました。A 3 years old boy named Suzuki Shin is lost.

But the last one seems to be confusing. Which is the appositive clause, what is the purpose of を before  お見かけのお客様, why do we use まで?

- 赤いTシャツを着て (wearing T-shirt)、紺の半ズボンをはいて (wearing navy blue 1/2 pants)、黄色い帽子をかぶっている (wearing yellow cap)３歳ぐらいの男のお子さん (about 3 years old boy)をお見かけのお客様、恐れ入りますが、最寄りの売り場までご連絡ください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「（3歳ぐらいの男のお子さん）をお見かけのお客様」 means like

> "**Some guest who saw** (an about 3 years old boy)"

So 「３歳ぐらいの男のお子さんをお見かけのお客様、最寄りの売り場までご連絡ください。」 means like

> "Some guest who saw an about 3 years old boy, please contact your near counter."

The sentence before お客様 expresses the target of the announcement,
and later, the announcement asks the guests to contact if they saw the boy by 「最寄りの売り場までご連絡ください」

「まで」 can be replaced with 「に」, but we Japanese prefer to use まで in reporting problems to someone. I don't know why.

By the way,
「お見かけ」 （original form is お見かけする） is the humble word（謙譲語） of 「見かける」 (see/find), and this is wrong usage for expressing お客様's action.
Either following sentence is correct.

> ３歳ぐらいの男のお子さんを見かけたお客様
>
> ３歳ぐらいの男のお子さんを見かけましたお客様

Comment: お見かけの is a respectful word and it's correct to apply to the customer's action. The original form is お見かけになる.